# visualizar posttypes no site wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Amigos estou estudando os posttypes esta rodando no ambiente de testes o CRUD.
Mas nao sei como faco para aparecer no site ex:
Se criei um posttype portfolio ou produtos por exemplo, como faco pra ficarem visíveis para pessoas verem, eles ficaram ocultos no admin, so no admin aparecem.

Usei os seguintes exemplos
http://tableless.com.br/custom-post-types-wordpress/
http://www.escolawp.com/2010/07/como-criar-custom-post-types-wordpress/

Como resolvo isso?
desde ja grato.

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas - o Wordpress segue um padrão para exibição de posts. Um ponto importante é a hierarquia de páginas utilizada pelo Wordpress, veja mais [aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Hierarquia_de_Modelos_WordPress).

Mas vamos aos exemplos práticos - vou utilizar como exemplo o post_type **carros**. - uma forma simples de testar se os posts types estão disponíveis é acessar a URL do seu site passando o parâmetro **post_type**. Exemplo: localhost/site **?post_type=carros**, onde **carros** é seu post_type. Ou, caso as configurações de permalink seja diferente da padrão: **localhost/site/carros**.

Caso não tenha modelo específico para seu post_type o Wordpress utilizará o **archive.php**, caso não encontre, utilizará o **index.php**. Se desejar criar um arquive para seu post_type basta criar um novo arquivo, em seu tema, seguindo o padrão **archive_[post_type].php**, exemplo: **archive-carros.php**, e neste arquivo poderá customizar seu layout para apresentar as informações conforme desejar.